# Can I tell if my stored proc is using the default value or an explicit value?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, default-value

I have a stored proc that takes in several parameters. One of these is a DateTime that has a default value of NULL.

Unfortunately, the column this will be written to is a nullable DateTime column. This is an issue as sometimes the parameter is ignored when the stored proc is called, but it ends up overwriting a valid datetime with null to the destination table.

Is there any T-SQL function or other way I can use to determine if the caller actually explicitly passed in NULL or simply ignored that parameter and left it to set the default value?

The only thing I can think of it to either;

1. Also have a flag saying indicating that the user wants to persist the DateTime information
2. Creating two versions of the stored proc; one with the DateTime param and no default value, and one that completely omits the DateTime param.

Neither seem like fantastic ideas, so any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Other than just checking whether your parameter value is NULL or not - no, not really. Nor should it ever matter whether a value for a stored proc is the defined default value or a supplied value - a value is a value is a value.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might approach this is to change the parameter default from `NULL` to a "magic" value - a date which your users are unlikely to enter - which you can then check for in the body of the stored procedure and act accordingly.

A good choice of magic value would be the beginning or end of the datetime range (`01 Jan 1753` or `31 Dec 9999`), depending on the actual data profile.